# Creating unique pages based on Mailchimp Merge Tags

Tags: node.js, email, express, mailchimp

: )

So, I'd like to send out an email (campaign) with the preview of an article, then I like to provide a link where users can read the full article on my website. On a sidebar, I'd like to show the user which newsletter lists they're subscribed to (and not subscribed to) so they might easily adjust their settings should they like to.

Once I have the user on the page, and my website knows their email address or the md5 hash of it. I can use the hash to interact with the MailChimp API (v3) to subscribe and unsubscribe them from various lists, but how do I get their information over to my website in the first place?

If I use the *|EMAIL|* merge tag in the "read full article" link, I put their plain text email in the query string of the URL. The *|UNIQID|* perhaps? I don't see what it does in the 3.0 API.

Side note: I'm aware that users who share this page, if the query strings contains a way to identify that user, they expose to their friends the ability to change their settings. I don't know how to avoid this either. Perhaps a redirect is best?

Sorry I don't have code yet.